# Get grandtotal for Row and Column using Pivot table or Any other method?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help in calculating Grand Total for Row and column for all 12 months using Pivot table or any other method to get the result.

Below is the sample table and its excepted output.

```
CREATE TABLE #MonthlyData (ID INT,MonthName VARCHAR(5),Col1 INT,Col2 INT,Col3 INT)

INSERT INTO #MonthlyData
VALUES(1, 'Jan',10,0,9),
(2,'Feb',0,10,1),
(3,'March',1,11,15),
(4,'April',0,20,10),
(5,'May', 0, 10, 1),
(6,'June',0,0,0),
(7,'July',10,10,10),
(8,'Aug',1,1,1),
(9,'Sept',20,10,30),
(10,'Oct',5,4,9),
(11,'Nov',10,10,10),
(12,'Dec',0,0,12)
```

Excepted Output:

```
Month   Col1    Col2    Col3    Total
Jan 10  0   9   19
Feb 0   10  1   11
March   1   11  15  27
April   0   20  10  30
May 0   10  1   11
June    0   0   0   0
July    10  10  10  30
Aug 1   1   1   3
Sept    20  10  30  60
Oct 5   4   9   18
Nov 10  10  10  30
Dec 0   0   12  12
Total   12  12  12  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `roll up` or similar mechanisms.  Personally, I prefer `grouping set`:

```
select coalesce(monthname, 'total'),  -- the cheap way to do this
       sum(col1) as col1, sum(col2) as col2, sum(col3) as col3,
       sum(col1 + col2 + col3) as total
from #MonthlyData md
group by grouping sets ( (monthname), () )
order by grouping(monthname) desc, min(id);
```

There are other methods, such as running two separate queries:

```
select monthname, col1, col2, col3, (col1 + col2 + col3)
from #MonthlyData
union all
select 'total' as monthname, sum(col1), sum(col2), sum(col3), sum(col1 + col2 + col3)
from #MonthlyData;
```

Comment: Used first query, Is there any other way to order by Months?  
 select coalesce(monthname, 'Total') AS Month, 
       sum(col1) as col1, sum(col2) as col2, sum(col3) as col3,
       sum(col1 + col2 + col3) as Total
from #MonthlyData md
group by grouping sets ( (monthname), () )
ORDER BY MIN(ID)

Comment: @user9017400  By adding the ID to the first grouping set. But the ORDER BY then needs to take consider a NULL.  
`select coalesce(monthname, 'Total') as Month, sum(col1) as Col1, sum(col2) as Col2, sum(col3) as Col3, sum(col1 + col2 + col3) as Total 
from #MonthlyData md 
group by grouping sets ((id, monthname),()) 
order by coalesce(id,max(id)+1)`